# How to determine why all Defender Firewall profiles are active?

Tags: networking, windows-10, firewall

In Windows 10, typically if I'm connected to a private network, looking at the Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security panel will only show the Private Profile as active. Currently, I'm seeing all 3 firewall profiles as active:

[image: Active Firewalls]

By clicking "View your network properties" in the Network Status settings, only one of the network adapters look active, and Network Category is "Private".

**(Edit:)** Compare this with another PC, which has a single Ethernet connection and is only using the private network, as expected.

[image: Private Network Only]

Is there any way to determine why all 3 firewall profiles are active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Get-NetConnectionProfile` powershell command to view the list of active network connections, including which network category (and thus which firewall profile) they are a part of.

In my case, it showed 3 connections due to my Ethernet connection and 2 separate VPN connections:

[image: Get-NetConnectionProfile results]

Answer (score 1):

There is a downloadable .pdf file from Microsoft
[PDF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/opbuildpdf/threat-protection/windows-firewall/TOC.pdf?branch=live) - Click save as (whatever you want to name it).

> **Enable Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security**

Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/windows-firewall-with-advanced-security-administration-with-windows-powershell

> Enable Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security
>
> Windows Defender Firewall drops traffic that does not correspond to allowed unsolicited traffic, or traffic that is sent in response to a request by the device. If you find that the rules you create are not being enforced, you may need to enable Windows Defender Firewall. Here is how to do this on a local domain device:
>
> **Netsh**
>
> syntax
>
> netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state on
>
> **Windows PowerShell**
>
> Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain,Public,Private -Enabled True

If you set one at a time you can set it the way you want them to be set.

**Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain -Enabled False**

Comment: I'm not interested in disabling the other firewall profiles, I'm looking more for the reason why it's using 3 profiles at the same time, instead of the typical 1 profile. I've added an edit with an additional screenshot showing what I expect from another computer, with only 1 active profile instead of 3.